# Custom Tool to Track last executed Query by External Application

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle

I am thinking to create a custom tool built using C# that will be able to connect to my current application session which has been connected to the database.

I imagine my custom tool will be able to accept the session id that is actively used by my other application.

Then, when my custom tool is connected to that session id, I will be able to track whichever SQL command is being executed by that session id on that application.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Thank you,

Hatjhie

Comment: Very interesting idea. Please explain what specific answers do you expect, and what specific problem do you have? A question formulated like this is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Your monitoring application will need to connect as a user with access to Oracle's dynamic views. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/REFRN/dynviews_part.htm#i403961).

To monitor sessions you will need `v$session`. To locate a session you will need to know the database USERNAME (or perhaps the external OSUSER or MACHINE). The session record will give you the SQL_ID which you can use to query views like `v$sqltext` and `v$sqltext_with_newlines`.

By default a user does not have access to V$ views. A DBA can grant the role `select_catalog_role` which allows you to read all the data dictionary views not just the V$ views. This is pretty powerful and generally it is better to grant select on specific views. Note that the views are named with an underscore, e.g. `v_$session`.